# ipad simulator not an option

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have Xcode 5 DP and am trying to run iPad applications. However it only shows "iOS Device" under the scheme and not a simulator. If I go to General --> Devices and change it from iPad to Universal I can only run the iPhone simulator but not the iPad one. There are no updates available for Xcode. Under Build Settings, I've tried changing the Code Signing Identity to Don't Sign but that didn't do anything. Also, I've changed the deployment target from iOS 7.0 to a lower version with no results. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not be using DP anymore as Xcode 5 is publicly available on the App Store. I suggest you delete your copy of Xcode and install from the App Store

Comment: +1 to dalton's suggestion. Install the current version of Xcode and try again. Make sure after installing Xcode you run through the extra step of downloading the additional components needed. Xcode should ask you to do so the first time you launch it.

Comment: I figured that since it said I was up to date, I was running the most current version of Xcode. I was always suspicious of it still saying DP. I have deleted it and am currently installing the most contemporary one. I will let you guys know how it goes. Thanks!